# How can I organize data hour-by-hour and set the missing values to zeros?

Tags: python, pandas

I played games several times a day and I got a score each time. I would like to reorganize the data hour-by-hour, and set the missing values to zero.

Here is the original data:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Time': ['2017-01-01 08:45:00', '2017-01-01 09:11:00', 
             '2017-01-01 11:40:00', '2017-01-01 14:05:00', 
             '2017-01-01 21:00:00'],
    'Score': range(1, 6)})
```

It looks like this:

```
   Score        Time
0   1   2017-01-01 08:45:00
1   2   2017-01-01 09:11:00
2   3   2017-01-01 11:40:00
3   4   2017-01-01 14:05:00
4   5   2017-01-01 15:00:00
```

How can I get a new dataframe like this:

```
day             Hour   Score
2017-01-01    00:00:00   0
       ... 
2017-01-01    08:00:00   1   
2017-01-01    09:00:00   2   
2017-01-01    10:00:00   0   
2017-01-01    11:00:00   3
2017-01-01    12:00:00   0
2017-01-01    13:00:00   0
2017-01-01    14:00:00   4
2017-01-01    15:00:00   5
2017-01-01    16:00:00   0
       ...  
2017-01-01    23:00:00   0
```

Many thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`resample`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html) with some aggregate function like `sum`, then [`fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html) and convert to to `int` by [`astype`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.astype.html) but first add `first` and `last` `DateTime` values:

```
df.loc[-1, 'Time'] = '2017-01-01 00:00:00'
df.loc[-2, 'Time'] = '2017-01-01 23:00:00'
df['Time'] =  pd.to_datetime(df['Time'])

df = df.resample('H', on='Time').sum().fillna(0).astype(int)
print (df)
                     Score
Time                      
2017-01-01 00:00:00      0
2017-01-01 01:00:00      0
2017-01-01 02:00:00      0
2017-01-01 03:00:00      0
2017-01-01 04:00:00      0
2017-01-01 05:00:00      0
2017-01-01 06:00:00      0
2017-01-01 07:00:00      0
2017-01-01 08:00:00      1
2017-01-01 09:00:00      2
2017-01-01 10:00:00      0
2017-01-01 11:00:00      3
2017-01-01 12:00:00      0
2017-01-01 13:00:00      0
2017-01-01 14:00:00      4
2017-01-01 15:00:00      0
2017-01-01 16:00:00      0
2017-01-01 17:00:00      0
2017-01-01 18:00:00      0
2017-01-01 19:00:00      0
2017-01-01 20:00:00      0
2017-01-01 21:00:00      5
2017-01-01 22:00:00      0
2017-01-01 23:00:00      0
```